# Is it "was" or "were?"

Tags: verbs

This question has got me baffled. Is it **"who was"** or **"who were"** in the sentence given below?

> One of the guys who were inside the car was dead.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence, *who were inside the car* is an adjective for the noun **Guys**. In other words, *were* is used for the plural **Guys**.

When you are referring to **One**, *was* would be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the sentence in two ways:

> (**One** of the guys), who **was** inside the car, was dead.

or

> One (of the **guys** who **were** inside the car) was dead.

Notice that in the first example, some commas are required. Parentheses are there just to highlight the grouping, not to alter the meaning; you get the correct sentences if you just delete them.

So your original sentence matches my second example exactly, and that is why **were** is the correct choice.